# haskell, is it possible to debug a parse error?

Tags: haskell

I am working through some exercises I found accompanying a set of lectures online and have come across a problem I cannot overcome, essentially, I have a function defined in a file as

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper ((x:x1:xs) len)
    | len > 2   = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper(xs (len - 1))
    | len == 2 = x : 2*x1
    | len == 1 = [2*x]
    | otherwise = []
```

and upon loading the file I get this(and only this):

```
Parse error in pattern: (x : x1 : xs)
```

Regardless of what the function may or may not do if I ever managed to load it, is there any way of getting ghci to tell me everything it was trying to parse in human readable form so that I can figure out these things for myself (i.e. if I can see what it was **actually** trying to parse (presumably garbage), as opposed to what I **think** it was trying to parse (a function name and two arguments: a list and an Int, and then the list to return dependent on the value of len) then fixing it should be a lot easier)?

All I know right now is that it is wrong ... for some reason (and even if some kind person tells me what was my mistake in this instance, I don't want to be stumped again by ever so slightly different problems in the future.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way to coerce GHCI to give you more information than that (although I'm admittedly not a very experienced GHCI user). Haskell errors can be very cryptic, but the ability to recognize and understand them will come with time and experience. In the meantime, I can give you a few tips on understanding and fixing that error:

- `Parse error` This means that GHCI was unable to understand the lexicographic structure of your code, regardless of what the code you wrote was supposed to do. Common causes of parse errors include inconsistent indentation and mismatched delimiters, such as an extra or missing closing `)`. This lets you know that there is a problem with the top-level syntax you are using, specifically:
- `in pattern:` Since you're using it in your code, I presume that you are familiar with [pattern matching](http://learnyouahaskell.com/syntax-in-functions). This lets us know that there is a problem with the syntax you are using in a pattern expression. Specifically, around this one:
- `(x : x1 : xs)` This is a valid pattern for matching a list of two or more elements. We know that this structure caused an error, but since it's valid in and of itself, we can conclude that this pattern caused a parse error because of the context in which it was used.

Widening our field of vision to look at the whole pattern, we spy an extraneous pair of parentheses surrounding the pattern that is throwing off the parser:

```
(   (x:x1:xs) len   ) --These should not be here
```

Since `(x:x1:xs)` and `len` are not part of the same data structure, they should not be placed together in parentheses (Haskell differs in this regard from many languages where all arguments in a function call are surrounded together by parentheses). Removing these parentheses fixes the parse error...

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len
    | len > 2   = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper(xs (len - 1))
    | len == 2 = x : 2*x1
    | len == 1 = [2*x]
    | otherwise = []
```

...but reveals a plethora of other errors sprinkled throughout our now lexicographically (but not logically correct function. Happy debugging!

Edit: it seemed rude to leave all those new errors there for you, so I fixed them. Here's a function that will compile correctly (although I haven't tested to see if it actually works or not):

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len --no parens around pattern
    --fixed parens to account for operator precedence
    | len > 2   = x : (2*x1) : (doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)) --removed parens around call to doubleEveryOtherHelper, same error as before
    | len == 2 = x : [2*x1]
    | len == 1 = [2*x]
    | otherwise = []
```

Note that lines 3 and 4 can be written much more clearly:

```
 | len > 2  = [x, 2*x1] ++ doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
 | len == 2 = [x, 2*x1]
```

Comment: in particular, note the same error in the recursive call to `doubleEveryOtherHelper`

Comment: thanks, this is a very helpful answer (and points me in the direction of what I should be reading about in more detail).

Comment: You don't actually need all those parentheses: `x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)` is OK. Also, `x : [2*x1]` is more commonly written as `[x, 2*x1]`.

Comment: @chi Of course! I can't believe I missed that. Thank you, that's a much more clear way of expressing that.

Comment: `| len > 2  = ([x, 2*x1] ++ doubleEveryOtherHelper xs) $ (len - 1)` is probably not what you intended...

Answer (score 2):

Others already pointed out the parsing errors. Let me add something on the logic errors in this code, even if not explicitly requested.

```
-- Syntactically fixed code
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len
    | len > 2   = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
    | len == 2 = x : 2*x1 : []
    | len == 1 = [2*x]
    | otherwise = []
```

I guess that the `len` parameter is meant to be the length of the integer list.

Now, the pattern `x:x1:xs` matches lists whose first element is `x`, and whose second element is `x1`. As such the pattern will *never* match with lists with less than two elements. This means that testing for `len==1` or `<1` will always fail.

The idiomatic way of doing this is to specify multiple patterns to match. Yours matches with lists at least 2 elements long, so let's cover the 0-long and 1-long lists with two patterns.

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper []        len = ???
doubleEveryOtherHelper [x]       len = ???
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len
    | len > 2   = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
    | len == 2 = x : 2*x1 : []
    | len == 1 = [2*x]
    | otherwise = []
```

Then, let's fill those `???` with the code from the bottom:

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper []        len = []    -- was in the oterwise case
doubleEveryOtherHelper [x]       len = [2*x] -- was in the len==1 case
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len
    | len > 2   = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
    | len == 2 = x : 2*x1 : []
```

Now, focus on the last line. When `len` is two, we must have `xs==[]`. Under that assumption, we have that `doubleEveryOtherHelper xs anyLength == []`, so we can make he code more complex by replacing `[]` in the last line with its equivalent `doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)`. Why should we make the code more complex?!? Well, the result of this is

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper []        len = []    -- was in the oterwise case
doubleEveryOtherHelper [x]       len = [2*x] -- was in the len==1 case
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len
    | len > 2  = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
    | len == 2 = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
```

making it obvious that the last two cases can be dealt with using the same code:

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> Int ->  [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper []        len = []   
doubleEveryOtherHelper [x]       len = [2*x]
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) len = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs (len - 1)
```

Now, we are not using the `len` parameter at all. So, if we agree on removing it on the calling sites we can remove it.

```
doubleEveryOtherHelper :: [Integer] -> [Integer]
doubleEveryOtherHelper []        = []   
doubleEveryOtherHelper [x]       = [2*x]
doubleEveryOtherHelper (x:x1:xs) = x : 2*x1 : doubleEveryOtherHelper xs
```

Much simpler, isn't it?

Note that there's still a bug in that `doubleEveryOtherHelper [1,2,3] = [1,4,6]` instead of `[1,4,3]`, which I believe should be the intended answer. I think you should now be able to fix it yourself.

Comment: Thanks for this one ... after getting my code to compile and having a play I saw that the approach I was taking wasn't really optimal, and actually found myself adopting essentially the same approach as here (though a match with [x] returns [x] not [2*x]). This is a good write up though

Answer (score 1):

Well, I know you want a method, not the answer, but let me start with the answer....  The error is that you are adding extra parenthes.  On the pattern matching side of the definition, parens mean something very different than on the right hand side (ie- they mean 'everything inside here matches exactly one parameter).  Remove the outer paren, the problem goes away.

As to the broader question, I don't actually know the answer about how to see what the grammar expected, but if it does exist, it is probably not as useful as you think it is.  Parsing errors are sort of the most basic types of errors, only triggering when the grammar of a language isn't satisfied.  Essentially, the compiler doesn't know what to do at all when this happens.  From an error reporting point of view, all the compiler can really do is show you the input when the error occurred, and perhaps show you a list of possible values that could have been expected.  The problem with the latter is that it often tends to be kind of overly wordy and not really useful....

Here is the thing though- Parse errors are really basic, and once you have written in the language for a short time, they are easy to spot.  The really interesting bugs (that will keep you up at night) are pretty much never parse errors.